# jQuery <h1> text from var dont wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The thing is, i'm creating a  element using jquery but when i set the Text attribute using the content from one varible, and when i open the html on the browser that text doesnt wrap in multiple lines like he does when i set the text manually.

Here is some of the code:

This mode doesnt wrap:

```
var Blue = "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN";

 $("h1",{
           'class': "nombre",
           'text':Blue,
            }).appendTo('#row'+i);
```

it looks like this on the browser:

```
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

This mode wrap:

```
  $("h1",{
           'class': "nombre",
           'text':"NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN",
            }).appendTo('#row'+i);
```

It looks like this on the browser:

```
NNNNNNNN-first line       
NNNNNNNN-second line
NNNNNNNN-third line
```

And this is what i need but using a var content, any ideas?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: using a variable and not should not make any difference... The functionality should be exactly the same.

Comment: I have to agree with @epascarello... Are you sure nothing else changes? Do you have an online sample or fiddle we could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `word-break: break-all;` to allow it to break text in the middle of the "word"

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Comment: Yees, it works, after around 3 hours wasted you save me, big thanks :)